# On which columns should I create the indexes

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, indexing

2 tables:

```
countries:
  id 
  short_name ("GE", "AR"...)
  long_name
  ....

banks:
  id
  name ("NATIONAL BANK OF COUNTRY123"...)
  country_id
  ...
```

Given that most often I'll be doing the following type of lookup:

```
select * from countries c
inner join banks b
on b.country_id = c.id
where c.short_name = ? and b.name = ?
```

on what columns should I create the indexes? I figure in `countries` I should create an additional index on `short_name` (`id` will remain as a primary, auto increment key). I don't know about `banks`, if I create an index on `name` which is a `varchar` string, will it be efficient and wise?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your query:

```
select *
from countries c inner join
     banks b
     on b.country_id = c.id
where c.short_name = ? and b.name = ?;
```

You have two indexing approaches.  The basic idea is that the SQL engine will find rows from one table (scan) and then look up values in the other.

The first possibility is "scan" `countries` and then lookup in `banks`:

```
countries(name, id)
banks(country_id, short_name)
```

The second possibility is "scan" `banks` and then lookup in `countries:

```
banks(short_name, country_id)
countries(id, name)
```

Which is actually better depends on the distribution of values in the data.  You can actually add both sets and let the SQL engine decide.

Comment: Take countries table. What index(es) could I add: 1) id and name 2) name_id (id and name_id) 3) id and id_name?

Comment: @Grienders . . . `country_id, id` and/or `id, name`.

Comment: 2 different indexes or 1 index on 2 columns?

Comment: @Grienders . . . Is there something unclear in my answer?  The appropriate indexes are composite indexes on each table.

Comment: Yes, unclear is "2 different indexes or 1 index on 2 columns? "

Comment: @Grienders . . . The answer includes the indexes.  They are composite indexes on each table.

Answer (score 1):

For `countries` table crate index on `short_name`. Combined index such as `(id, short_name)` is waste of resources - why: `id` is primary key - unique, so look up by first component (id) already gives one row, what benefit from second component? I think `short_name` also is unique, so the same about `(short_name, id)`.

Other situation with `banks` table. `country_id` is not unique here, so you can benefit from index: `(country_id, name)`

I think these two additional indexes are enough for your query.

Comment: but "name" in banks can be pretty long like "The national bank of the Republic Kongo". Are you sure it's sensible to create an index on it?

Comment: Without index on `name`, but with `banks(country_id)` will be scan by `name` as many rows as there are banks around the country. If the number of banks in one country is not significant (say 10) then you can use the index `banks(country_id)`. I suggest to test - if the search speed with this index does not suit you needs then create index `banks(country_id, name)`

Comment: Rimas, you didn't understand. That's an easy "yes-no" question. --- "but "name" in banks can be pretty long like "The national bank of the Republic Kongo". Are you sure it's sensible to create an index on it? "

Comment: Index on long column also speed up look up. But such an index uses more space - so I suggested experiment with this index and without it.

Answer (score 0):

Add indices on the columns which are numerical like integer, double of data types... Also those columns which are used in where clause, can have the indices...

Comment: Avoid adding unused indexes because they will do nothing but slow down updates/inserts.  Having 1 or 2 extra won't be debilitating, but if you ever reach 10 or 20 it will be very noticeable, and it can be time consuming to pinpoint exactly which of them are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out which indexes you need is to test them out.  I hope you have a dev environment set up for this purpose that you can load with production data (pg_dump and pg_restore).

If your table is small enough, it may not be helpful to index it at all.  Your countries table (assuming it's a list of countries), for instance, probably doesn't need an index on anything.

If you're always querying on bank name, and the banks table has > 10K records, a `banks(name)` index will help.  If you ever want to get a list of banks in a country, however, indexing `banks(country_id)` will be good too.

If you really care about your query performance, start with no indexes and test each one to figure out how much benefit it gives.  PostgreSQL's explain analyze tool is excellent, but using [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com) will do a bit of extra math for you to figure out exactly how long each component takes.

Comment: 1) how to test whether or not they need the indexes? 2) "name" of a bank is varchar of length being about 30 symbols. Is it wise to create an index on it? Won't that harm performance?

Comment: From experience I wouldn't worry about a varchar(30) field being too big to index - I've never had any problems.  Also, I'd recommend just using text unless you explicitly want to truncate the name length.  [The difference in peformence is negligible.](http://www.depesz.com/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/)  To test this stuff: 1) load production schema/data into your dev database with pg_dump/restore. 2) test example query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  3) Experiment with indexes that you think would speed up slow parts of the query from step 2.  4) repeat 2 and 3 until satisfied.